# Unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js

Full Error:

FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mydomain.in/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://mydomain.in/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

EDIT: Same error in localhost also.

My firebase-messaging-sw.js is in public folder, if that helps.

firebase-messaging-sw.js code:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js");

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    all keys here
  });
}

messaging
  .getToken()
  .then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
      sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log(
        "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
      );
      // Show permission UI.
      updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
    showToken("Error retrieving Instance ID token. ", err);
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });

firebase.messaging();
```